# Too many redirects for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am getting too many redirects for my site: [www.camerasfor.net](http://www.camerasfor.net)

However the site is working properly on browser, but on analysis it shows them, due to which I am getting TooManyRedirectException in my code for a small api hosted there in.

The hosting guys have no clue of it, what to do ?

I am attaching screen-shot along with this.

Thanks[image]

This is my .htaccess, can this be an issue ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the result that your screenshot shows. Maybe the server is 302 redirecting for certain user agents. It also might help if you post an access log from the web server.

Comment: Try the redirect checker using "Chrome" as the user agent and it won't show a redirect loop. You must be doing some additional redirects based on user agent string.

Comment: @RyanBurnette : Oh yes, you are correct, but when I run a small php scrip in code, I am getting many redirects. How shall I fix this ? Can it be due to some plugin etc ?

Comment: I don't have enough information to say. You can try disable plugins and themes until it goes away. Add them back until the problem returns and you'll narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @RyanBurnette : I tried but I think the issue is with hosting or some other file like htaccess, since my other sites hosted there are facing the same issue.

Comment: @RyanBurnette : I have pasted my .htaccess file, see if this might be an issue..